# Transform Google Analytics 4 datalayer to braze purchase

Tags: javascript, google-datalayer

I would like to use our GA4 (Google Analytics 4) purchase datalayer to send those information to our customer engagement tool braze. I am not sure how to loop through the GA4 items and pass them to braze. Any help is highly appreciated!

The GA4 datalayer looks like that:

```
dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
dataLayer.push({
  event: "purchase",
  ecommerce: {
      transaction_id: "T_12345",
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      value: 25.42,
      tax: 4.90,
      shipping: 5.99,
      currency: "USD",
      coupon: "SUMMER_SALE",
      items: [
       {
        item_id: "SKU_12345",
        item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
        affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
        coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
        currency: "USD",
        discount: 2.22,
        index: 0,
        item_brand: "Google",
        item_category: "Apparel",
        item_category2: "Adult",
        item_category3: "Shirts",
        item_category4: "Crew",
        item_category5: "Short sleeve",
        item_list_id: "related_products",
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        item_variant: "green",
        location_id: "L_12345",
        price: 9.99,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        item_id: "SKU_12346",
        item_name: "Google Grey Women's Tee",
        affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
        coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
        currency: "USD",
        discount: 3.33,
        index: 1,
        item_brand: "Google",
        item_category: "Apparel",
        item_category2: "Adult",
        item_category3: "Shirts",
        item_category4: "Crew",
        item_category5: "Short sleeve",
        item_list_id: "related_products",
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        item_variant: "gray",
        location_id: "L_12345",
        price: 20.99,
        promotion_id: "P_12345",
        promotion_name: "Summer Sale",
        quantity: 1
      }]
  }
});
```

To log purchases in braze the data needs to adjust to the braze model:

`braze.logPurchase(productId, price, currency, quantity);`

The mapping would be the following:

braze        GA4

---

productID -> item_id

price     -> price

currency  -> currency

quantity  -> quantity

Answer (score 0):

Braze now supports E-Commerce tags with their Google Tag Manager integration: https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/web/google_tag_manager/#ecommerce